# detect call and show popup from asterisk in php

Tags: php, asterisk, asteriskami

I want to detect asterisk call to php project.
my asterisk server is linux and I am run php script on another windows server.
Now what should I do?

Answer (score -1):

You should use AMI or ARI interface and catch call events.